# Issue binding this.getPlace() of an autocomplete places Object within backbone.js and Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, ninja-forms

I'm currently working on building a custom places autocomplete field utilising the Google Maps Places API for the Wordpress plugin Ninja Forms. Ninja Forms uses backbone.js and Marionette to listen to, trigger and render after/before various events etc

So, rather than going over all the numerous things that didn't work, I'll include my current workings and the various places where the variable I want is defined and undefined. I feel like fundamentally this is a javascript issue, however, I have used every trick I can in the book to get things to work, e.g., `var self = this;` prior to the calling of the event listener. It's going to be very hard to replicate my situation fully, but I believe HTML with an input field with an `id` attribute of `addressAutoComplete` might be sufficient for this to work.

```
'use strict';

(function ($) {
    var nfRadio = Backbone.Radio;

    var addressAutoCompleteFrontEndController = Marionette.Object.extend({

        address: "",
        formattedAddress: "",
        autocompleteAddressField: {},
        autocompleteOn: 0,
        autocomplete: {},

        initialize: function initialize() {
            // On the Field's model value change...
            var fieldsChannel = nfRadio.channel('fields');
            this.listenTo(fieldsChannel, 'keyup:field', this.onKeyup);
            this.listenTo(fieldsChannel, 'blur:field', this.onBlur);
        },

        onKeyup: function(model) {
            var place;
            this.autocompleteAddressField = document.getElementById('addressAutoComplete');
            this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.autocompleteAddressField, {types: ['geocode']} );
            this.autocompleteOn = 1;

            var self = this;
            this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                place = this.getPlace();
                self.formattedAddress = place.formatted_address;
                console.log(place.formatted_address); // Defined
            });

            console.log(this.formattedAddress); // Undefinied
        },

        onBlur: function(model) {
            var place;
            this.autocompleteAddressField = document.getElementById('addressAutoComplete');
            this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.autocompleteAddressField, {types: ['geocode']} );
            this.autocompleteOn = 1;

            var self = this;
            this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                place = this.getPlace();
                self.formattedAddress = place.formatted_address;
                console.log(place.formatted_address); // Defined
            });

            console.log(this.formattedAddress); // Undefined
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        new addressAutoCompleteFrontEndController();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

So, in effect, inside the `this.autocomplete.addListener` callback function - I have full access to `place.formatted_address` and this gives me what I what from the user selection. But I can't seem to bind it to `this.formattedAddress` ... I'm hoping there's a JS expert who can just say, "all you need to do is this...". Hopefully! :D

Additional thoughts: I don't think I can use ES6 syntax for this. I was thinking I could maybe make use of the arrow function `=>` ??

Comment: You might want to take a step back and explain the actual problem, it doesn't look like adding event listeners inside event listeners is the right approach... you probably need to use some API of the widget you are trying to use/promises...

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `console.log(this.formattedAddress); // Undefined` before the `place_changed` callback is fired, which sets `this.formattedAddress`.

Until a `keyup` or `blur` happens, which sets up a `place_changed` event listener, and then when a `place_changed` event actually triggers, only then the binding happens.
Before that happens, it's undefined. And that is what you see in the console.

If you move `console.log(this.formattedAddress);` inside the callback you'll see the binding happens indeed.

---

BTW it looks like you are adding event listeners inside an event listener without any cleanup, which is very evil. Every time a `keyup` or `blur` happens you're adding new event listeners that does the same thing to the autocomplete.

Comment: Hi @TJ , of course - this is a slight mashup of the Google tutorial on how to get the places API to work with an input field and my limited knowledge of backbone.js and Marionette. If I moved it to the initilizer function, it doesn't work. If I move it to the onBlur function, it needs two clicks to begin. Keyup works nicely. I do have the autoCompleteOn flag to call it only once tho. Left that out of the question to avoid unnecessary complications. I'm still none the wiser from your answer tho, because I still can't seem set `this.formattedAddress` from inside the listener function...

Comment: I explained why it requires two clicks and what is happening and how to check/prove it is being set, but you are just printing it at a point in time when it is still undefined. Please try reading the answer again/ create an [mcve] and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In other words, the problem you have is not about "context", it is about "when" code executes, it has to do with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. "The callback" ie the function you pass to `addListener`, executes AFTER (at a later point in time) `console.log(this.formattedAddress); // Undefined`

Comment: Hi TJ, yes, and I have explained that is where I am lost. I'm trying to set the objects attributes as `this.` or `self.` but they're not being set - at all. They should be set once, and then they should be usable later down the line. I believe it's more an issue with Marionette than the async nature of Javascript. I'm extending a Marionette object where the options (object's attributes) I have specified do not exist when the Marionette object creates.

Comment: I see... so you are only expecting it to be set after some user interaction. Is it possible to create an [mcve] so we can check why the context is changing?

Comment: Hi TJ, managed to get the triggering event working correctly on this. It's difficult to get a minimal example working because I was working on a child plugin of a Wordpress plugin and it's very yucky to set things up (even in Codepen).